# Common group from two selects, sql server

Tags: sql-server, select, join

How do I union or join or CTE two selects, so that I only get the results that exists in both

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM ads WHERE status <> 'BASIC'
```

Let's say the result set is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM ads WHERE state = 'Alabama'
```

Let's say the result set is 2, 4, 5, 8, 9

Then I want 2, 4 and 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [`INTERSECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) does.

I removed `DISTINCT` from the queries as this is implied by `INTERSECT` in SQL Server (it does not implement `INTERSECT ALL`)

```
SELECT userid
FROM   ads
WHERE  status <> 'BASIC'
INTERSECT
SELECT userid
FROM   ads
WHERE  state = 'Alabama'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never heard of that one, but extremely useful in many scenarios, I would say. I can see there is also an 'EXCEPT' which I suppose in this example would return all userids who had upgraded ads but no ads at all in Alabama